# How to use Genetic Algorithm to find weight of voting classifier in WEKA?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, weka, genetic-algorithm, voting

I am working from [this article](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.artmed.2017.12.001): "A novel method for predicting kidney stone type using ensemble learning". The author used a genetic algorithm for finding the optimal weight vector for voting with WEKA, but i don't know see can they did that. How can i use a genetic algorithm to find weight of voting classifier with WEKA?

This below paragraph has been extracted from the article:

> In order to enhance the performance of the voting algorithm,a weighted
>   majority vote is used. Simple majority vote algorithm is usually an
>   effective way to combine different classifiers, but not all
>   classifiers have the same effect on the classification problem. To
>   optimize the results from weight majority vote classifier, we need to
>   find the optimal weight vector. Applying Genetic algorithms is our
>   solution for finding the optimal weight vector in this problem.

Comment: I don't have access to the article, but any decent article using GAs contains the following:

(1) Which GA was used, or pseudocode (ideally actual source code) for the custom GA.
(2) Parameter values for the GA
(3) How many evaluations / generations the GA ran for
(4) How many random seeds were tried and what the distribution of results was.

If the paper is missing this information, somebody is practicing shoddy scholarship and this should color your evaluation of whatever else the paper is reporting.  It's probably B.S.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some trained classifiers and a test set, you can create a method `calculateFitness(double[] weights)`. In this method for each `Instance` calculate all predictions and a merged prediction according to the `weights`. Use the combined predictions and the real values to calculate the total score you want to maximize/minimize.

Using the calculateFitness method you can create a custom GA to find best weights.